# Prove that |R[0,1)| <= |F| where F is the set of all functions from N to {0,1}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I believe that I need to show that there's a one-to-one function from R[0,1) to F and that I can do this by associating the decimal expansion .b_1b_2b_3... etc with a function f(n) that is either 0 or 1 based on some property of the digit b_n in the decimal expansion. I'm having trouble coming up with such a function.

Comment: And what is $R[0,1)$? The interval $[0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Why decimal? Binary might be easier.

Comment: Yes to T. Bongers.